# Fast compare IEEE float greater than zero by cheating

Tags: c++, optimization, floating-point, compare, ieee

I am working on a platform that has terrible stalls when comparing floats to zero. As an optimization I have seen the following code used:

```
inline bool GreaterThanZero( float value )
{
   const int value_as_int = *(int*)&value;
   return ( value_as_int > 0 );
}
```

Looking at the generated assembly the stalls are gone and the function is more performant.

Does this work? I'm confused because all of the optimizations for IEEE tricks use SIGNMASKS and lots of AND/OR operations (https://www.lomont.org/papers/2005/CompareFloat.pdf for example). Does the cast to a signed int help? Testing in a simple harness detects no problems.

Any insight would be good.

Comment: Basically, the trick is to check high-order bit. The high order bit is 0 for non-negative integers in two's complement representation, and 1 for negative integers. Largely by coincidence, that same bit is also used as sign bit in IEEE floating point representation.

Comment: It works, but would a compiler really not do the optimal thing for something as simple as `f > 0`?

Comment: @Barry if the platform has terrible stalls while comparing for 0f it doesn't sound like any consumer platform I know of. Sounds like a special piece of hardware to me.

Comment: @Barry This is not premature optimization; code runs faster with this change, and no the compiler is not smart enough. I wish it were. I have better things to worry about than fixing 3D overlap tests that run slow because of comparisons to zero!

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik - thanks, that makes sense.

Comment: With the code in the question, a quiet NAN will be deemed `> 0`... bit dodgy but may be fine for many applications.  Lots of juicy details of bit layout on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik not so much coincidence. The IEEE floating point was intelligently designed. I still don't understand why the pure floating-point code would be much slower for such a simple test though.

Comment: Ignoring strict-aliasing crap, this almost works.  You've implemented the comparison `!(x <= 0)` rather than `x > 0`.

Comment: @tmyklebu what's the difference? They're logically equivalent.

Comment: @MarkRansom: They're not.  `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, and `==` always return false if at least one argument is a NaN.  (And actually, thinking for another ten seconds, he hasn't implemented the comparison `!(x <= 0)` either.  It's `x > 0` for finite `x` and true for some NaNs but not others.

Comment: Is your platform lacking an FPU ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The expression `*(int*)&value > 0` tests if `value` is any positive float, from the smallest positive denormal (which has the same representation as `0x00000001`) to the largest finite float (with representation `0x7f7fffff`) and `+inf` (which has the same representation as `0x7f800000`). The trick detects as positive a number of, but not all, NaN representations (the NaN representations above `0x7f800001`). It is fine if you don't care about some values of NaN making the test true.

This all works because of the [representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) of IEEE 754 formats.

The bit manipulation functions that you saw in the literature for the purpose of emulating IEEE 754 operations were probably aiming for perfect emulation, taking into account the particular behaviors of `NaN` and signed zeroes. For instance, the variation `*(int*)&value >= 0` would not be equivalent to `value >= 0.0f`, because `-0.0f`, represented as `0x80000000` as an unsigned int and thus as `-0x80000000` as a signed one, makes the latter condition true and the former one false. This can make such functions quite complicated.

> Does the cast to a signed `int` help?

Well, yes, because the sign bits of `float` and `int` are in the same place and both indicate a positive number when unset. But the condition `value > 0.0f` could be implemented by re-interpreting `value` as an unsigned integer too.

---

Note: the conversion to `int*` of the address of `value` breaks strict aliasing rules, but this may be acceptable if your compiler guarantees that it gives meaning to these programs (perhaps with a command-line option).

Comment: How about converting to `unsigned int` and checking if it's less than 0x80000001u?  Also, I think it might be cleaner and more efficient to have a function receive a `union` which has both a `float` member and an `int` member, and have a macro which casts a floating-point operand and calls that function, since on many platforms `float` parameters are passed in FPU registers, but here the value is needed as an integer.

Comment: @supercat I don't see how “converting to unsigned int and checking if it's less than 0x80000001u” comes close to separating the floats that make `f > 0` true from those that don't.

Comment: It would pick up negative zero as being >=0; whether or not it picks up NaN values as well would depend upon the platform, but I would suspect that in many situations negative zeroes pose the larger problem.

Comment: @supercat The original question is about `f > 0`. The remark in my answer about `f >= 0` is only that, a remark.

Comment: Gotcha. For testing strictly greater than zero, how about `((unsigned)i-1u) < (0x7F800000-1u))`?  I think that would regard all negative numbers as well as both zeroes and all NaNs as being not greater than zero.